# How can I stripe the HTML <b> tag and replace it with <h>?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a program called anki, a SRS for learning languages. In anki I have a deck where 1000 cards have a code like this `<b>TEXT</b>`.
Now I want to replace the `<b>` and `</b>` with `<h>` and `</h>` to make it look like this `<h>TEXT</h>`, but I don't know how to do it. I tried something like this, which didn't work. I would appreciate any help.

```
<div id="sentence">
{{front}}
</div>

<script>
s = document.querySelector('#sentence');
s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(/.*<b>(.*)<\/b>.*/, '<p>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace them individually:

```js
s = document.querySelector('#sentence');
s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(/<b>/g, '<h>');
s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML.replace(/<\/b>/g, '</h>');
```

Comment: I tried the code, sadly it doesn't work. I get this message.

https://pastebin.com/J3vj8LQs

I think it is anki's fault or rather the way card template is coded. I'll try changing it up, but thanks for the code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the slash